# Should searching for a substring of a key in a trie return true?

Tags: data-structures, trie

Say I have an empty trie T, and then I do T.insert("hello"). If I perform T.find("hell") then is that supposed to return true or false?

Comment: why should it return `true`?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to. If you need that behavior, you probably want a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) or a generalized suffix tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should return all the partial matches, so in the case you're talking about should return `{"hello"}`, if it doesn't have a match would normally expect it to be an empty set being returned or null

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you store a word, you terminate with a node using a character like '*'.

Then implement a partial match method which returns true if your trie contains an appropriate path.

Then implement a full match method which is defined like

```
full_match(x): return partial_match(x + "*")
```